# Is it possible to install iMovie 9 on El Capitan?

Tags: imovie

Is it possible to copy iMovie 9 from my OS X Yosemite MacBook and install it in a new MacBook I am yet to buy and will have OS X El Capitan and iMovie 10?

iMovie 10 has very limited export options compared to iMovie 9. So I would like to copy iMovie 9 from my old computer to my new computer. If this is not possible, is there any other way to install iMovie 9 on El Capitan that already has iMovie 10 installed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. iMovie.app copied from older computer to newer computer with El Capitan works.

(Apple store employee said it would not. Confirmed that it is wrong)

Answer (score 0):

Do not upgrade to El Capitan if you want to use iMovie 9. It will not support still photos in your video. And if you try to type a title into your video iMovie 9 will crash.

Answer (score -1):

Don't. I was told by Apple tech that iMovie 9 was not designed to work with El Capitan.

Comment: I was able to install it on a new Macbook with El Capitan and my simple video editing and exporting works just like before.